# Generating a list of all strings possible using 6 characters

Tags: python-3.x

I need to generate a list that contains all possible 4 character strings made up of the characters A,B,C,D,E,F. What is the best way to accomplish this? Characters can be used any number of times.

Comment: This seems to very clearly be a homework assignment. Please post the code you have already made a good faith attempt with and ask a specific question about that code. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: This is for a small portion of an assignment, yes. I dont have much in the way of relevant code, but ill keep that in mind.

Comment: See the link I gave. In general the community doesn't mind homework questions, but you and the community will get more out of it if you try it first and ask specific questions about your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list("".join(l) for l in itertools.product('ABCDEF', repeat=4))
```

Comment: @user2782067 If you are doing an assignment, ask yourself if this is the code your instructor is expecting you to be able to write.